# Does the 5TB Seagate Backup Plus external hard drive support hardware encryption?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, encryption, portable-harddrive

In SeaTools, the Drive Information feature shows:

```
Encryption Support: Self Encrypting Drive
Security Mode: Supported
```

I cannot find any encryption-related options in the relevant Seagate software (SeaTools, Toolkit and DiscWizard), and all of the marketing material points towards the "Backup Plus Ultra Touch", a lower capacity model with fancy fabric on the case, as their only current model of 2.5" external hard drive supporting hardware encryption.

Does the "Backup Plus Ultra Touch" model have some physical difference to support hardware encryption, suggesting SeaTools is reporting this incorrectly, or are Seagate withholding this feature by omitting it in their software for models that would otherwise support it?

Comment: The actual HDD likely supports it but it’s likely a feature of a specific model of that product.  I am guessing you don’t have a Backup Plus Ultra Touch?

Comment: No, just the Backup Plus, so I can't compare directly compare them

Comment: Seagate says it does>>>>https://www.seagate.com/manuals/backup-plus-ultra-touch/use-toolkit/

Comment: That's the Ultra Touch, a different model